# my self-signed https website does not work in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, certificate, self-signed

I have a secure ssl website that uses self-signed certificate. Everything seems to be working just fine in Firefox and IE but in Chrome browser. It just keep trying to download the page but neither page or error comes back. When i looked in the developer tool, it shows status as pending for my URL and nothing else. I am using Chrome Ver 30. Can you guys help me to resolve this?

I tried to Google this problem but have no luck.. I am not sure if it is a solution, but I do not want to install any certificate on the client browser. That doesn’t seems to be a good solution at all, because there will be several people using my site and I am not going to ask them to install certificate just to use my site.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you add details on how you are creating the cert (and what settings it is using)? Also, try disabling any chrome extensions.

Comment: I am using the following article to setup SSL:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-multiple-ssl-certificates-on-one-ip-with-apache-on-ubuntu-12-04

Using following command:

sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com/apache.key –out /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com/apache.crt